# Docker Startup Multiple service is not working

Tags: docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM drupal

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openssh-server -y
RUN apt-get install -y supervisor

#SS Related Fix : https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3621
RUN mkdir -p /run/sshd

# SS Access Configuration
RUN echo "root:Docker!" | chpasswd

#Project Uplaod
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*
COPY ./html/ /var/www/html/


# Startup Configuration
COPY servername.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/servername.conf
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf


CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

**Start Command** : docker -D run -p 80:80 -p 2222:22 -it  /bin/bash

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:SSH]
command=/usr/sbin/sshd start


[program:Apache]
command=/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

when i jump into Shell and run that command it works but when i start container its not starting up the web server.

Answer (score 0):

As standing in [documentation](http://supervisord.org/running.html)

> To start supervisord, run $BINDIR/supervisord. The resulting process
>   will daemonize itself and detach from the terminal. It keeps an
>   operations log at $CWD/supervisor.log by default.
>
> **You may start the supervisord executable in the foreground by passing
>   the -n flag on its command line. This is useful to debug startup
>   problems.**

So systemd detach from main process what means for docker that process ended - exit container. To solve your problem you need to change CMD section to

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
docker -D run -p 80:80 -p 2222:22 -it /bin/bash
```

The last part of the command, `/bin/bash`, replaces the `CMD` in the Dockerfile, so you *only* get the GNU bash shell.  You should remove that part of the line and the standard command from your image will run.

You might consider how much you actually need an interactive shell in your Docker environment.  Most application images are set up to run totally on their own without manual setup steps; compare the stock `mysql` or `nginx` images, for instance, which don't include any kind of remote login system.  Also consider that anyone who can run `docker history` can now trivially find out your root password, and you have no way to manage the sshd host keys.  I'd suggest removing this entire supervisord/sshd system and just packaging your application.